# Highlight current line in org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, highlighting, hl-line-mode

Running Doom Emacs v2.0.9 on Emacs 27.1.

In the agenda buffer, how do I get the current line highlighted?

`global-hl-line-mode` is enabled and the current line in other buffers is highlighted as expected.

However, agenda buffer does not show this highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook #'hl-line-mode)

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Even you are using `global-hl-line-mode`. You have to still be sure local variables(Which can be different for different buffers) are correct.

I have like that definition in my files. Reverse should be correct for you.

```
  ;; Don' use globl-hl-line-in-org-agenda
  (add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local global-hl-line-mode nil)))
```

I highly recommend to use `helpful` package to see this variables in good format.

Comment: Thanks. But disabling `global-hl-line-mode` while in an agenda buffer did not change the display. Also, the solution suggested by @gigiair worked perfectly.

Comment: `(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local global-hl-line-mode t)))` ? weird that it didn't work.